# Getting an error that function name is not defined

Tags: python, encoding

I've just started to mess around with "coding" recently and i tried to make this:

```
cake=4

def test():
    if cake<6:
        return "Less cake"

    elif cake>3:
        return "Enough cake"

    else:
        return "I dont want any cake"
```

but, when i try to run it, and call "test" it says it's not defined. What can i do to fix it?

UPDATE: Thanks to everyone for helping!

Comment: Did you copy/paste your code or does it have indentations?

Comment: If your code doesn't have any indentations (and looks exactly like you've pasted here), then it means that the lines following `def test():` are not part of the function definition.

Comment: They are indented, spaced it all out so you could see what was the code

Comment: @blubby Why did you edit your code in question. This way you have made your question off-topic, error can not reproduced anymore. You may as well delete it.

Comment: @blubby, try with my answer and check.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file test.py and add the below codes in it and execute like:-

`python test.py`

```
cake=4

def test():
  if (cake < 6):
    return "Less cake"
  elif (cake>3):
    return "Enough cake"
  else:
    return "I dont want any cake"

print(test())
#or
order=test()
print(order)
```